# How to access my web page localstorage from Crossrider extension?

Tags: local-storage, crossrider

I want to be notified in my Crossrider extension when a user comes to my site and when the new information is saved to localstorage.  When there's a notification, the extension will need to read from and write to the localstorage of my site.  How can I accomplish this using the db api?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From your question I understand you want the extension to know when:

1. a user visits your site
2. changes are saved to your local database

You can achieve these goals as follows:

1. use the [CrossriderAPI.events](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/CrossriderAPI.events) methods to communicate between the required pages on your website and your extension. Simply add the snippets for firing the extension event to the  required pages and in your *extension.js* add the code for handling the event fired by the page. If you require any assistance with this, please feel free to email the Crossrider support team: support@crossrider.com.
2. as there are no events to inform you when the local database is updated, you can monitor/poll the keys you are interested in to determine whether they have changed. For example, in your *extension.js* file the following code polls the **myKey** every second:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  var prevValue = null;
  // Poll every second
  appAPI.setInterval(function() {
    var currValue = appAPI.db.get('myKey');
    if (currValue !== prevValue) {
      // change detected; update prevValue and doSomething
      prevValue = currValue;
      doSomething();
    }
  }, 1000);

  function doSomething() { ... }
});
```

[**Disclosure**] I am a Crossrider employee